# Merge two csv files based on key and secondary key

Tags: python, csv

I would like to merge two csv files as follows:

**csv1:**

```
formula,solver,runtime,conflicts
CBS_k3_n100_m403_b30_13.cnf,SWDiA5BY,0.001842,318
CBS_k3_n100_m403_b30_13.cnf,glucose,0.001842,318
```

**csv2:**

```
formula,entropy,num sols
CBS_k3_n100_m403_b30_13.cnf,0.202,707286
```

**desired output:**

```
formula,solver,runtime,conflicts,entropy,solutions
CBS_k3_n100_m403_b30_13.cnf,SWDiA5BY,0.001842,318,0.202,707286
CBS_k3_n100_m403_b30_13.cnf,glucose,0.001842,318,0.202,707286
```

So I did an intersection between the keys of the two dictionaries (csv's), and used list comprehension

```
keysA = set(dict1.keys())
keysB = set(dict2.keys())
keys = keysA & keysB
...
[[key] + dict1.get(key, []) + dict2.get(key, []) for key in keys]
```

but there are some 'duplicate' rows (which I need) where the field **formula** is the same but the field **solver** isn't, and my output is:

```
formula,solver,runtime,conflicts,entropy,solutions
CBS_k3_n100_m403_b30_13.cnf,SWDiA5BY,0.001842,318,0.202,707286
```

How can I keep those rows using list comprehension? or in any other way

appreciate your help

EDIT - added an example

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are these "duplicate rows" all in csv1, the only file where **solver** is present? Just how do you want duplicate rows treated? You can have at most one value for each key, but that value could be a list. Do you want a list of values for each **formula**? You should show us an example of data and the desired result from that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use pandas. Its pretty easy to do this in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv("1.csv")
df=pd.read_csv("2.csv")
result=df1.merge(df,on="formula")
result.to_csv("result.csv")
```

also you can use `result=df1.merge(df,on="formula",how="outer")` to keep those formula that one of your csv has but other doesn't

Comment: I believe you meant `result=df1.merge(df,on="formula",how="left")` , because outer join keeps all rows, thanks!

Comment: `"left"` means the left outer join that means row that `df` has exclusively will be lost in `result`.Here I am talking about the full outer join to keep all.